# The authenticate function return always none Django Project

Tags: mysql, django, authentication, backend, django-registration

I am working on a vehicle project management system, and using a custom table for storing the signup details in MySQL. When the user logins the authenticate function returns none always, I am using email and password fields for login

1. checked the values are retrieving from database correctly or not
2. The backend authentication

Here is userProfile model

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
full_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
phone_number=models.IntegerField()
email=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
# is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
# is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'phone_number']
def set_password(self, password):
    self.password = make_password(password)
def check_password(self, password):
    return check_password(password, self.password)
```

'

```
def userLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        print('from loginhtml page',email,password)
        try:
            user_profile = UserProfiles.objects.get(email=email)
            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            print("from database  ",user_profile.email,user_profile.password)
            print(user)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, 'You have been logged in successfully.')
                return redirect('/DashboardPage.html')
            else:
                error_message='Invalid email or password. Please try again.'
                messages.error(request, error_message)
        except UserProfiles.DoesNotExist:
            error_message='Invalid email or password. Please try again.'
            messages.error(request, error_message)

    return render(request, 'userLogin.html')
```

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.shortcuts import redirect

from .models import UserProfiles
class UserProfileBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = UserProfiles.objects.get(email=email)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserProfiles.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Vehicle Parking Management System - User Login</title>
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'styles/loginstyle.css' %} ">

    </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-primary" href="#">Vehicle Parking Management System</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
         </nav>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-5"><em><strong>Welcome to the Vehicle Parking Management System</strong></em></h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title text-center">User Login</h5>
              <form action="{% url 'parkingapp:userLogin' %}" method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="email">Email Address</label>
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  name='email' placeholder="Enter your email address">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password">
                </div>

                      {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
            {% for message in messages %}
                <li>{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
              </form>
              <div class="text-center">
              
            <p class="text-center">Don't have an existing account? <a href="{% url 'parkingapp:userSignup' %}" class="btn btn-link">Sign up here</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
   <script src="{% static 'js/loginscript.js' %}"></script>
            </body>
            </html>
```

I also tried this code , result is none

```
testuser = authenticate(username='sim@example.com', password='sim')
        print(testuser)
```

Then tried printing the data fetching from table, It is retrieving the email and password.

`user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password) print("from database  ",user_profile.email,user_profile.password) print(user)`

from loginhtml page vim@gmail.com vim
from database   vim@gmail.com vim
None
None

Comment: You should use some view name in `redirect()` say for example `return redirect("dashboard")`

Comment: Can you share your `UserProfiles` model?

Comment: class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    full_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone_number=models.IntegerField()
    email=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=20)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    # is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    # is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name', 'phone_number']
    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password = make_password(password)
    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password(password, self.password)

Comment: Share it in question by editing, it's not clear in comments.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your code. The main one being the `User` model. You are not using Django's, which is a bad practice. Take a look at this [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example). I would recommend to rebuild your model based on this.

Now, related to your current problem, that is happening because of the fields you are calling on `authenticate` and the fields you set in the custom `backend`.

views.py

```py
def userLogin(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        try:
            ...
            user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
            ...
            
    return render(request, 'userLogin.html')
```

backend.py

```py
class UserProfileBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, email=None, password=None): # Here is the problem
        try:
            user = UserProfiles.objects.get(email=email) # Also happens in this line
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserProfiles.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

As you can see, you pass `username` as a param in `authenticate`, but try to catch it as `email` in your custom backend. And, since `email` is always none, so is the `user`, just modify the param accordingly:

```py
class UserProfileBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = UserProfiles.objects.get(email=username)
            if user.check_password(password):
                return user
        except UserProfiles.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Although, even if you fix that, another error is raised because you are not using Django's `User` model (missing a field required in `login`). So we need to modify yours:

models.py

```py
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

And, of course add the backend to `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`:

settings.py

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['core.backend.UserProfileBackend']
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort to detail explanation of the problem, Highly appreciates. as a newbie in the platform I was confused that how can auth_user hold  admin and multiple user. So I thought to make a custom model for users. I Changed as you mentioned and can you please explain core.backend.UserProfileBackend'  as i am getting error                                                        ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'core'
Any way Thank you friend

Comment: `core` is the name of my application module. you should replace with your app name. Forgot to mention that ^^". It is the path to your backend class `appname.filename.ClassName` (but of course you can place it where you want, just need point to it correctly).

Comment: Changed that also, but still same issue user is none

Comment: Could you share the process or view you are using to create your custom `User` objects? If you followed everything, the only explanation is that credentials are wrong, in this case probably the password (be sure you are using `.set_password`).

Comment: Hi, Please find the following code alsoclass CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The Email field must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

Comment: I meant how you are creating objects with your custom `User` model. If it is returning none after you implemented everything I posted on my answer, the only reason is wrong credentials. The process should be something like: `UserProfiles(full_name='Test User', phone_number=123456789, email='test@example.com')` to create an instance. Then  `user.set_password('testpass123')` to set the password. And, `user.save()`. (Again, the password needs to be hashed)

Comment: user =CustomUser.objects.create_user(username=email, email=email, password=password)
        user.full_name = full_name
        user.phone_number = phone_number
        user.save()

Comment: There is your problem. Password is not being hashed and when it is not, `check_password` will return `False`. Use the creation process I described above and it should work. :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the model to Django's built in table auth user and changed the code according to that. It worked for me.

Here is my views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'adminPage.html')

def userSignup(request):
      print("hello inside usersignup")
      if request.method == 'POST':
          print("hello inside POST")
          username=request.POST['user_name']
          full_name = request.POST['full_name']
          email = request.POST['email']
          password = request.POST['password']
          print("hello THE CTEDENTIALS ARE")
          print(full_name,email,password)
         
       user=User.objects.create_user(username=username,first_name=full_name, email=email,password=password)
        
        user.save()
        user = authenticate(request, username=email, password=password)
        if user is not None and hasattr(user, '_meta'):
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
            return redirect('Veh_App:DashboardPage')

      messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
      return render(request, 'userSignup.html')

def userLogin(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        username=request.POST.get('username')
        pass1=request.POST.get('password')
        print(username,pass1)
        user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=pass1)
        print(user)
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            messages.info(request, f"You are now logged in as {username}.")
            return redirect('Veh_App:DashboardPage')
        else:
            context = {'error': 'Invalid credentials'}
            return render(request, 'userlogin.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'userLogin.html')

def LogoutPage(request):
    print("In logout bef")
    logout(request)
    print("after")
    messages.info(request, "You have successfully logged out.")
    print("In logout")
    return redirect('index')


@login_required(login_url='login')
def DashboardPage(request):
    return render(request,'DashboardPage.html')

@csrf_protect
def loginadmin(request):
    return render(request, 'admin_login.html')
```